# Terminal Concentrate Program's output to string?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, terminal

In terminal I used to run:

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

suppose I have a python script called `test.py` which outputs version number, how can I insert that version inside the above url to replace `101.0.4951.41`

My try was to write this:

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/+'python3 test.py'+/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

I would prefer a 1 like solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the output of test.py into your url following this pattern:

```sh
echo 101.0.4951.41 | (read var; wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$var/chromedriver_linux64.zip)
```

Outputs:

```
*file download logs*
```

Simply replace `echo 101.0.4951.41` with `python3 test.py`.

Comment: @Omer I believe that's a problem with your python script, not my answer. I'd dig into that last bit `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'``

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run your command from the `test.py` itself:

```
import os
version = "101.0.4951.41"
os.system(f"wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/{version}/chromedriver_linux64.zip")
```

Then run it like: `python test.py`

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for approach to do this in terminal just to learn something new :)